# Refund test order on Google Play

Tags: android, testing, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

How to refund in app purchase payed with test card?

I use "consume"-button in my debug version, but I wouldn't use it in release version (I don't want to show this button to end-users).

I see charded Test order in Google Play Console > Order management, but Button "Refund" is disabled: "The selected orders can’t be refunded either due to their age, status or your lack of requisite permissions".

Is there non-programming solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: my refund button is no longer greyed out. Give it a try!**

There is no way to do this without extra work. Came across [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8n4rdi/fyi_you_can_no_longer_refund_cancel_test/) - it looks like it used to be possible a couple of months ago.

Here's Google's quote from the link:

> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support!
>
> Unfortunately we don't currently support a way to cancel/consume test purchases through the console, you can only do so programatically.